# Remove content line breaks tsv

Tags: php, regex, excel, csv

I am trying to clean up a TSV file (Copy from excel spreadsheet) for reading into PHP.

What I need to be able to do is remove any line breaks from the content part of the TSV but not the line break at the end of each line, any idea how this can be accomplished by using regex or another function.

Example data (I've highlighted tabs):

```
[tab]Some tab seperated data[tab]"
Here is some text that someone has used alt+enter to insert a new line into
• One.
• Two
• Three
"[tab][tab][tab][tab]Some data[tab][tab]Some other data[final-line-break]
```

Edit: Upon further investigation it appears if excel encounters a " in the actual cell value, it will delimit it as "" which will cause issues with the regex below, does anyone else have a solution?

Comment: In other words, you want to remove line breaks between double quotes?

Comment: Yes - that is a much simpler way of putting it!

Comment: Can we find escaped quotes `""` outside the quoted content?

Comment: If there is a cell with a double quote but without a new line, the double quote will not be escaped. If the cell has a double quote AND a new line, the whole cell will be wrapped in double quotes and the double quote will be escaped.

Comment: Ok, it's more clear now. I will update my pattern for that. Last thing, Is the first cell of a line delimited on the left by a tab? (or nothing?)

Answer (score 0):

The main difficulty is to differentiate opening quotes form closing quotes.

You can use this replacement *(I have putted a # as replacement string only to see, you can obviously use what you want, a space, an empty string...)*:

```
$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~
(?:            # entry points:
    (?!\A)\G   #   - contiguous to a precedent match
  |            #   OR
    (?:^|\t)"  #"# - quote preceded by a start of line or a tab 
)

(?>
    [^\r\n"\t]+ #"# all execpt tabs, newlines and quotes
  |
    ""          # escaped quote
)*
\K              # remove all on the left from match result
(?:
    \R          # newline
  |
    "(*SKIP)(?!) #"# closing quote (skipped)
)
~xm
EOD;

$data = preg_replace($pattern, '#', $data);
```

The match can only begin with one of the two entry point. The first match use the opening quote, the next use the `(?!\A)\G` entry point. `\G` is an anchor for the end of the precedent match, but since it can match the start of the string too, I added `(?!\A)` that means *not followed by the start of the string* to avoid this possibility.

The `\K` removes all that has been matched before from the match result. With this trick, nothing on the left is replaced.

`\R` stands for a newline regardless of the OS (however, I assume that it is probably `\r\n` in your case).

`"` will match the closing quote. But since you don't want to replace it, I forces the pattern to fail with `(?!)` *(not followed by nothing)*.

The `(*SKIP)` backtracking control verb forbids to retry characters matched before in case of failing. That is very useful because without it the closing quote can be see as a new opening quote by the pattern at the next iteration. With this, the regex engine will continue to search only after the closing quote.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem:

```
/\n(.+\n[^\t])+.+/
```

With the pattern above, you can grab the string exactly between the quotes you mentioned.

From here you can use preg match and the pattern to grab the string between the quotes. Then use pre_replace to replace the new lines as you wish.

preg_replace ("/\n/", "", $match);